# What is the best way to handle modal dialog using Watin

Tags: c#-4.0, watin, ui-testing

It is not clear at all how to test modal dialogs using Watin. AlertDialogHandler(with usingOnce, waituntilexists etc) does not work and blogs talk about using ie.HtmlDialog  (ie is their browser object). However the HtmlDialog method does not exist anymore. Thanks in advance !

Comment: ie.HtmlDialog exists in WatiN 2.1.  Post specifics of your code.

Comment: hmm yeah it does, I was using a browser object like this though:
`Browser browser = Browser.AttachTo<FireFox>(Find.ByUrl("my url"))`
and this "browser" object does not have an HTML dialog so I was confused. Seems like I will be forced to use IE

Comment: Thanks! works now. Even if I specify the type as IE that is use the object like `Browser browser = Browser.AttachTo<IE>(...)` the HtmlDialog is not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HtmlDialog is a method on the IE class, not on the browser class.  HtmlDialog is not available for the Firefox browser.

_You'll need to do something like _

```
IE myIEbrowser = Browser.AttachTo<IE>(...);
myIEBrowser.HtmlDialog....
```

_Not _

```
Browser myGenericBrowser = Browser.AttachTo<IE>(...)
myGenericBrowser.HtmlDialog(....    <-  This won't work because the HtmlDialog doesn't exist in the base Browser class.
```

This is for WatiN 2.1